# How to install driver WIRELESS BROADCOM BCM4313 802.11 or ETHERNET QUALCOMM AR8162 (OFFLINE) for lenovo G480

Tags: 12.04

configuration to lenovo :

```
lenovo@ubuntu:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at f0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f0615000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0619000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f0610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f0500000-f05fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: f0400000-f04fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f0618000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    I/O ports at 3088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
    Memory at f0617000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 7
    Memory at f0614000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 0587
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: brcmsmac
    Kernel modules: bcma, brcmsmac

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at f0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Broadcom BCM4313, download the DEB files for your OS. You'll need the b43-fwcutter and the firmware-b43-installer files. This worked for me on a Dell D620 laptop.

You can find links to both from launchpad

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/b43-fwcutter

Answer (score 0):

The driver needed for BCM4313 comes preinstalled with Ubuntu. I recently helped a friend of mine to set up Ubuntu and he was using this exact WiFi chip.

However, we ran into the problem that the WiFi card didn't start on boot time, which we circumvented by adding the command `rfkill unblock all` as a startup program.

As for the Qualcomm Ethernet card, I've never encountered it before and therefore can't tell you whether it will work out of the box or where to find drivers.

Comment: in that this command is executed when